# how to create dataframe in UDF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem. I want to create a DataFrame in UDF and use my model to transform it to another. But I get this Exception. Is there something wrong in Spark Conf? I don't know. Is there anyone can help me to solve this problem?

**Code:**

```
val model = PipelineModel.load("/user/abel/model/pipeline_model")
val modelBroad = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(model)

def model_predict(id:Long, text:String):Double = {
  val modelLoaded = modelBroad.value
  val sparkss = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  val dataDF = sparkss.createDataFrame(Seq((id,text))).toDF("id","text")
  val result = modelLoaded.transform(dataDF).select("prediction").collect().apply(0).getDouble(0)
  println(f"The prediction of $id and $text is $result")
  result
}

val udf_func = udf(model_predict _)
test.withColumn("prediction",udf_func($"id",$"text")).show()
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.sparkContext(SparkPlan.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.metrics$lzycompute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.metrics(LocalTableScanExec.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.resetMetrics(SparkPlan.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withAction$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$withAction$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreach(TreeNode.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3365)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collect(Dataset.scala:2788)
        at com.zamplus.mine.SparkSubmit$.com$zamplus$mine$SparkSubmit$$model_predict$1(SparkSubmit.scala:21)
        at com.zamplus.mine.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:40)
        at com.zamplus.mine.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:40)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: SparkSession (`spark`) and SparkContext (`sc`) are available only on master. Not on workers. You cannot submit a new job to the SparkSession from inside a udf AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your UDF. UDF runs on multiple instances and uses all variables that we are using inside it. So you should passed all required global variable as a parameters such as `modelBroad` otherwise it will give you `null pointer exception`.

There are few more good practice that you are not following in UDF. Some of are:

1. You do not need to create `spark session` in UDF. Otherwise it will create multiple spark session and which will cause issues. Instead of this pass global spark session as a variable in UDF if required.
2. Remove unnecessary pritnln in UDF, which effect your return also.

I have changed your code just for reference. It is just a prototype of ideal UDF. Please change it accordingly.

```
val sparkss = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val model = PipelineModel.load("/user/abel/model/pipeline_model")
val modelBroad = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(model)

def model_predict(id:Long, text:String,spark:SparkSession,modelBroad:<datatype>):Double = {
  val modelLoaded = modelBroad.value
  val dataDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((id,text))).toDF("id","text")
  val result = modelLoaded.transform(dataDF).select("prediction").collect().apply(0).getDouble(0)
  result
}

val udf_func = udf(model_predict _)
test.withColumn("prediction",udf_func($"id",$"text",lit(sparkss),lit(modelBroad))).show()
```

Comment: Thank you! but I still got the *nullPointerException*

Comment: can you update in your question whatever you have tried ?